# Query posts by Post title

Tags: wp-query

I use the following ACF query to generate a list, works perfectly.

Now, however, I want to order my list by standard WP “post title” instead of ACF custom field “datum”

How can I do that ?

```
// args
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 999,
   'post_type'   => 'lezing',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_key' => 'datum',
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'key' => 'jaar',
         'value' => '2019',
      ),
   )
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I don't think this code works. You cannot use curly quotes (`‘`) in PHP. :)

Comment: @fuxia - you beat me to the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

That query has nothing to do with ACF. It's a regular post query using WordPress' standard query class. As such you can refer to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) for the options for ordering your query.

To sort by post title you just need to set `orderby` to `title`:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'post_type'      => 'lezing',
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'jaar',
            'value' => '2019',
        ),
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Also note that the quote marks in your original question are incorrect. You need to use non-fancy quotes like `'`. This can be an issue if you're copying code from incorrectly formatted blog/forum posts.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will order using the meta term. To order by the post title, you just need to change the `orderby` to `title`.

Take a look at the documentation for what the parameters mean:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand.

I have changed the code and it works!

Thanks again,

Greetings Peter